# Label shown twice Swift

Tags: ios, swift, label, counter

i have got a problem with my Counter application. When starting the counter everything works fine, but the label is showing the initial value 0.0 plus in addition the new time += 0.2. See the result at the foto below. Does anyone have a solution? Thank you!

```
import UIKit

class CounterViewController: UIViewController {

var time = 0.0
var timer = Timer()

@IBOutlet weak var timerLabel:UILabel!

@IBAction func startCounter(_ sender:UIButton){
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.2, target: self, selector:#selector(CounterViewController.startAction), userInfo:nil, repeats: true)

}

@IBAction func pauseCounter(_ sender:UIButton){
    timer.invalidate()
}

@IBAction func stopCounter(_ sender:UIButton){
    timer.invalidate()
    time = 0.0
    timerLabel.text = "\(time)"
}
@objc func startAction(){
    time += 0.2
    timerLabel.text = "\(time)"
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
}
}
```

[see label twice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUxhP.png)

Comment: Check your storyboard; I suspect you have added two labels to your scene. One is linked to the outlet and the other is just sitting there showing 0

Comment: This would appear to be using a storyboard (or xib file) as you have an IBOutlet and IBActions.  How is this setup?  You haven't added a label twice in that have you?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this in timer declaration

```
var timer:Timer?
```

and set this in viewDidLoad

```
timerLabel.text = "0.0"
```

Also check your xib or storyboard If added same label twice

Comment: Don't forget this will change the timer property to an optional and you will need to adjust the code accordingly.

Comment: yes i know , declaring a timer like = timer() is not appropriate

Comment: I assumed you knew I was just pointing it out for anyone that might wonder why there are suddenly errors all over the place.  I fully agree the original declaration using Timer() is wrong.